# How to count a row in group but one number one time php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to count number of shops which buy brand 1 brand 2 or brand 3. but pne shop count one time. but in my query it count total num of rows for each brand. can anyone correct my query?

```
                            --- product ---

                       id  pcode   pname   brand
                       1   123     Dalda   1
                       2   124     Habib   1
                       3   125     Sufi    2
                       4   126     Toyota  3

                       ---------SALE-----------                 
                    id  shcode  shname  pcode   pname   amount
                    1      1    A G/S    123    DALDA   1020
                    2      1    A G/S    124    HABIB   1030
                    3      2    B G/S    125    SUFI    1040
                    4      2    B G/S    123    DALDA   1020
                    5      2    B G/S    126    TOYOTA  1050
                    6      3    C G/S    123    DALDA   1020
                    7      4    D G/S    125    SUFI    1040
                    8      4    D G/S    123    DALDA   1020
                    9      4    D G/S    124    HABIB   1030
                   10      4    D G/S    126    TOYOTA  1050
                   11      5    E G/S    123    DALDA   1020
                   12      6    F G/S    125    SUFI    1040
                   13      7    G G/S    126    TOYOTA  1050


                               MY REQUIRED RESULT   
                                BRAND   Shops
                                   1    5
                                   2    3
                                   3    3
```

my query

```
select p.brand, count(s.shcode) AS shops
            FROM product p 
            INNER JOIN sdetail s on s.pcode = p.pcode
            GROUP BY p.brand
```

Comment: Brand 1 have only 5 shops ????what bour pcode 124 ??

Comment: can you explain the relation between two tables?

Comment: in first table i define a brand for all products. and then i want to count shops group by brand. because in second table there is no brand. i am taking it from 1st table.

Comment: ok...number of shops mentioned for brand 1 is wrong rite ? it should be 7 as per data in your table

Comment: no it is five. if he buy 2 products of one brand then it must be count as 1 not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tmp.brand, count(tmp.shcode) AS shops FROM (
                                           SELECT DISTINCT temp.brand, (SELECT DISTINCT temp.shcode) AS shcode FROM (SELECT p.brand, s.shcode
                                                                FROM product p 
                                                                INNER JOIN sdetail s on s.pcode = p.pcode) AS temp
                                          ) AS tmp GROUP BY tmp.brand
```

Logic : Join two table, get the distinct shop brand pairs, group them by brand and get the shop count.

Comment: if i use this query this will count number of rows and then group it by brand. but i want to count every shop one time

Comment: Edited the answer please check it, I have not tested it, please post here if you found any issues

Comment: select p.brand, count(DISTINCT  s.shcode) AS shops
            FROM product p 
            INNER JOIN sdetail s on s.pcode = p.pcode
            GROUP BY p.brand

Comment: yup more simpler answer, but you will get result from my query too :)

Comment: Thanks Prasanth Bendra. You help me a lot. Hope you will continue in future. as i was a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a distinct around the shcode in your count function. So try this:

```
select p.brand, count(distinct(s.shcode)) AS shops
        FROM product p 
        INNER JOIN sdetail s on s.pcode = p.pcode
        GROUP BY p.brand
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92aa3/7) to play with this..

Comment: Thanks Man. U r also help full

Comment: You're welcome! Just as a side note, if performance on large datasets is an issue then I would suggest using a simple count distinct. You can compare the execution plans of various solutions and then choose what is best for you.